# Handling no file exists situations

Tags: xml, ssis

In My Package in SSIS to read xml data from one directory and then after that move the xml data to another Directory. But I have Problem with my Package when have no xml data in old Directory error come and I want my Package automatic working read xml data when I have xml data in Directory and when I do not have then working without error because not find xml data in directory. I mean work the package always every Hour without Error even no xml data in Directory.

Answer (score 0):

we can do in different ways, One way is to create 'Script Task' at the top, where you can 'look for the particular folder or file types ..etc and set one global variable'. and after Script task ends you can verify the Global variable value and make the necessary steps.
As per your condition, if files are there and set the variable value true/false. if true then proceed for next steps. If the value is false (No files in the folder) mean, it won't process next steps, it will skip. your package won't fail.

Example below, you can verify the condition as part of 'fx' function after script task.

[image]